# Determine when text exceeds a specific height

Tags: javascript, html, angular

Using angular and typescript I need to be able to close the tag of a paragraph `<p>` when the text exceeds a container height.
Let's say I have a `<div>` with a height of `200px`. When adding an object inside the div `<div style="height: 200px"><p>{{text}}</p></div>` I need to be able to determine when the text becomes larger than the 200px of text that the container can hold.

Is there any event from javascript that I haven't found?

Comment: you could use `overflow-y:auto` then check the `scrollHeight` of the div if it is more than 200 you should get your answer

Comment: You could set `overflow:hidden;`. The text would still be there, but anything beyond the 200px wouldn't show.

Comment: @joyBlanks, thanks. This might be a viable way. Although I am not sure how to determine on which char in the paragraph I need to cut off the text. Any ideas?

Comment: @Ouroborus, thank you for your comment but this is not the behaviour I was asking for. Hiding the overflow does the trick visually but I need to know when the hiding starts in order to cut off the text manually since I need to place the overflown text somewhere else.